# MediaMonkey "There was a problem querying the database" on XP netbook

Tags: windows-xp, mediamonkey

On MediaMonkey, when i run it, it gives me the following error: "There was an error querying the database: Error executing SQL "SELECT * FROM Filters ORDER BY Pos" : No such table: Filters(1, 1)

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I found that the MediaMonkey support is top-notch. My question was answered in less than 12 hours and I was only using the free version of the software. You really should ask them; they'll probably have an answer for you.

**Edit:** One other thing. I have found that if problems do appear with MediaMonkey, using a **beta** version usually solves it. They have a very active development cycle, so bugs are solved rather fast. Instead of waiting for an official release, a beta version could do the trick; the [MediaMonkey forum](http://www.mediamonkey.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=6) has a wealth of information, including links to beta and RC versions.

Comment: I'd second that, and the problem was one of my own making!